# Express port error on running grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

eoIm trying to run an application with a grunt task, but cannot get rid of this error:

```
Running "concurrent:clientDevDemo" (concurrent) task
Running "watch:clientDev" (watch) task
Running "nodemon:demoServer" (nodemon) task
Waiting...
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: demo/server/***/*
[nodemon] starting `node demo/server/app.js`
Loading express server...
Static server running at http://localhost:7676/
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:14)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1240:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/leo/dev/vm1/ui/demo/server/app.js:48:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Does anyone knows how to kill the process running on the port/s?

Thanks

Comment: Why not increment the port number for your spawned process / server...? Can we see your grunt code?

Comment: Yeah, change the port was the easiest temporary solution.